# Removing duplicate columns from a pandas dataframe: behavior of transpose + drop_duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

So I was playing around with `drop_duplicates()`. Say I have a dataframe with duplicate columns:

```
In [9]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame( data=nr.random((3,2)) )
df1
Out[9]:
0   1
0    0.441663    0.396479
1    0.079502    0.715348
2    0.692295    0.069418
3 rows × 2 columns
In [10]:

df2 = pd.concat( ( df1, df1 ), axis=1 )
df2
Out[10]:
0   1   0   1
0    0.441663    0.396479    0.441663    0.396479
1    0.079502    0.715348    0.079502    0.715348
2    0.692295    0.069418    0.692295    0.069418
3 rows × 4 columns
In [11]:
```

I want to remove duplicate columns. The following works:

```
df2.T.drop_duplicates().T
Out[12]:
0   1
0    0.441663    0.396479
1    0.079502    0.715348
2    0.692295    0.069418
3 rows × 2 columns
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
df2.T.drop_duplicates( inplace=True )
df2
Out[11]:
0   1   0   1
0    0.441663    0.396479    0.441663    0.396479
1    0.079502    0.715348    0.079502    0.715348
2    0.692295    0.069418    0.692295    0.069418
3 rows × 4 columns
In [12]:
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd form *does* work (`df.T.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)`), but it is operating on a copy (the transpose itself doesn't copy, but the `drop_duplicates` DOES); so it is modifying a copy that you then don't have a reference.

Almost all pandas operations return a new object; that is the correct idiom, `inplace` is a convience feature and must be used with care (or IMHO very very rarely).

Comment: Now I am confused. Isn't `inplace` used to explicitely avoid copies?

Comment: only a small subset of operations can actually be done w/o using a copy. MOST inplace operations behind the scene actually make a copy. That's why IMHO ``inplace`` operations are syntatically burdensome, and mostly useless.